# How do I get this website table to include a border?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, outline

I am programming a website for work (have almost no coding experience, so I might be missing crucial info - will update as needed). DOCTYPE html Public, link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"

```
<div id="main">
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<...>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</div><!--#main -->
```

I've set up a table of names using following formatting in the .html doc:

```
<div id="main">
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<...>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</div><!--#main -->
```

Now, in style.css, tables are defined as follows

```
table.hist-table {
width:98%;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
font-size:12px;
border-spacing:0px;
}
.hist-table tr{
border:1px solid #CCC;
}
.hist-table .row1 td {
padding: 4px;
margin: 3px;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
vertical-align: text-top;
background-color: #eff0f1;
}

.his-table th {
padding:4px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #00274c;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
}

#header {
margin-top: 30px;
clear:both;
background: #536a93;
background: #00274c;
padding: 0px 0 10px 60px;
margin: 0 4.6%
font-size: 11px;
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

For some reason, when opening the .html webpage, the table does not include a border, so it is very difficult to distinguish the rows of text from one another. Does anyone have a possible solution?

Comment: "You got your <html> tag in my <div> tag!"  "You've got your <div> tag surrounding my <html> tag!"  These two great tastes do NOT go together like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're .html document should be set up as follows,

```
<...DOCTYPE etc...>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<table>
Table contents...
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is because your  tags should encompas almost all of your document. The  and  tags should both be encompased by the  tag. Then within your  tag should be all of your external links to your css files, external fonts etc.

Inside of your  tag should be all of the , ,  and all of the other tags.

I hope this helps. I may not have understood all of your points but it looks the be the arrangement of your html document that is the problem. :)